# Can reflection API cause race condition in synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading, reflection

If there are multiple threads accessing a synchronized block,we know that race condition will not occur.But if we use Reflection API to change an instance variable,will it cause race condition.If it does,how should we properly use Reflection API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if we use Reflection API to change an instance variable, will it cause race condition?

Absolutely, it will.

> If it does,how should we properly use Reflection API?

You can synchronize on the object whose properties you set, like this:

```
Object obj = ...
Field f = c.getDeclaredField("...");
synchronize(obj) {
    f.set(obj, newVal);
}
```